# How can it be formally proved that $f \in O(⌊f ⌋)$

Tags: runtime-analysis, proof-techniques, big-o-notation

I'm trying to prove that $f \in \mathcal{O}(\lfloor f \rfloor)$ given that $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, f(m) \geq 1$

Here's what I've thought of so far,
we can set C = 10 and k = 1 and somehow prove that this would eventually dominate the function?
Not sure how I can prove this without a concrete function defined for $f$

According to the definition of big O, [image]

For any C larger than 1, C times floor of f would eventually dominate f. What I can't figure out is how to outline this in a formal proof.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I rewrote my answer in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{f\}<1\le\lfloor f\rfloor\implies f=\lfloor f\rfloor+\{f\}<2\lfloor f\rfloor.$$

---

Together with $2\lfloor f\rfloor\le2f$, that makes $f=\Theta(\lfloor f\rfloor)$.

[image]